# A conjecture regarding a strange infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, conjectures

Numerical calculations indicate that the following conjecture is true
$$
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\prod _{k=0}^{n-1} \left(x+e^{-k}\right)}{\prod _{k=0}^n \left(1+te^{-k}\right)}t^n =\frac{1}{1-xt}.\tag{1}
$$
Here the $n=0th$ term of the sum is $\frac{1}{1+t}$ to avoid confucion.

> **Question.** Is the conjecture (1) correct?

This sum emerged in certain birth and death process calculations. I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: What happens if you replace $1/e$ by any rational number less than 1 and greater than 0?

Comment: @JamesArathoon if $e$ is replaced by any number greater than 1 then (1) is surpizingly correct too.

Comment: Since the conjecture is $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\prod _{k=0}^{n} \left(1+\frac{q^{-k}}{x}\right)}{(1+\frac{q^{-n}}{x})\prod _{k=0}^n \left(1+t \;q^{-k}\right)} x^n t^n=\frac{1}{1-xt}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }x^n t^n$, where q is rational greater than 1, you can simplify to use a single variable, either $x$ or $t$ variable on its own.

Comment: The conjecture is clearly false when $0<x$ and $\frac{1}{x}<t$.